# How in javascript to make a form disappear on submission

Tags: javascript, forms, hide

I have a form at the top of my html page which I want to have disappear after I submit the form.  My code (below), while it temporarily hides the form, insists on the forming then becoming visible again.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Owen Walker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form" onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="first_div" style="visibility:hidden">Second</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    document.getElementById("form" ).style.display = "none";  
    document.getElementById("first_div" ).style.visibility = "visible";
alert("after"); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to prevent your form from being submitted and reloading the page. Change the form line to:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
```

and after the alert in your function add:

```
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks! The two changes worked perfectly. (Don't know why, though.)

Comment: Because in order to stop the submit event, you need to return false.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use JQuery as it is a powerful tool for doing this type of stuffs without hassle...
  well you can do it in this way

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form" onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="first_div" style="visibility:hidden">Second</div>

<script>
// using JQuery
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               $("#form").submit();
               $("#form").hide();
               alert("Your form was successfully submitted");
            });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`
note the use of preventDefault() to preventing it from submitting the form when you click submit.